# Error in relational query in Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have the following select statement, but it giving me errors. When I query separately it works. I tried under query editor also. Same error.

```
List<Deposit_Detail__c> depositDetailList = [Select Deposit__r.Name,  Id,Amount__c, Member_Name__c from Deposit_Detail__c Where Id IN :trigger.new];
```

The error is as follows:

> Select Deposit__r.Name, Id,Amount__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:8 Didn't understand relationship 'Deposit__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name.

Note that its nothing to do with trigger.new. I removed the trigger.new from the select entry. still has  error. The same way I did it in other triigers/classes and its works. The following code works as an example:

```
List<Receipts_Payments__c> memberList = [Select Member__r.Id, Member__r.Name, Member__r.Email__c, 
        Id, Member__c, RecordTypeId from Receipts_Payments__c where Id IN :trigger.new
        ];
```

But  this one doesn't.

```
List<Deposit_Detail__c> depositDetailList = [Select Deposit__r.Name,  Id,Amount__c, Member_Name__c from Deposit_Detail__c Where Id IN :trigger.new];
```

I even tried to use child to parent relationship query, that doesn't too.

Parent object API name : `Deposit__c`
Child Object API Name: `Deposit_Detail__c`
Child Relationship Name : `Deposit_Details`

I don't know whether the error is related to object itself.

Comment: what's the actual API field name of the lookup/master-detail of `Deposit__c` on the `Deposit_Detail__c` object.

Comment: Most likely it is deposits__r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to use the lookup field with the extension __r in order to access the parent Object's fields as below:

If the lookup field API name instead of using the parent Object name in the SOQL query.If both are different then this error occurs.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. It works